# understanding crashlytics report

Tags: core-foundation, crashlytics

I've embedded crashlytics in my ios app. run the application and it crashed... I've got the following information on my dashboard and I don't know how to read the report, and what to fix.

the issue reported is:

```
1   CoreFoundation        objectIsKindOfClass
```

infographics shows:

- 21.3GB free space
- 23 MB free RAM
- 13% RAM (when looking in more details)
- 76% disk space (when looking in more details)

the data

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x50000008

0    libobjc.A.dylib  _cache_getImp + 3
2    libobjc.A.dylib  class_respondsToSelector + 30
3    CoreFoundation   objectIsKindOfClass + 36
4    CoreFoundation   __handleUncaughtException + 68
13   UIKit            UIApplicationMain + 1120
14   MyApp            main.m line 16
```

the raw info looks like this:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39c33584 _cache_getImp + 3
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39c33fa5 lookUpMethod + 28
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39c351e7 class_respondsToSelector + 30
3  CoreFoundation                 0x31f3d755 objectIsKindOfClass + 36
4  CoreFoundation                 0x31f3d4a1 __handleUncaughtException + 68
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39c38a49 _objc_terminate() + 128
6  libc++abi.dylib                0x3968511b safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 78
7  libc++abi.dylib                0x396851b4 std::terminate() + 19
8  libc++abi.dylib                0x3968662b __cxa_rethrow + 94
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39c389b5 objc_exception_rethrow + 12
10 CoreFoundation                 0x31e842a1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456
11 CoreFoundation                 0x31e840c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
12 GraphicsServices               0x35a6333b GSEventRunModal + 74
13 UIKit                          0x33da02b9 UIApplicationMain + 1120
14 MyApp                          0x000af5a1 main (main.m:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial to understand the crash report
https://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs
.

Hope it helps you

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).